# How do I rename a variable/method and all references in it in C# VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I see how to do it in javascript:
https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/

But it doesn't seem to work with C# for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select a piece of text and right-click it. The context menu has "change all occurences". but it only works for the open file in the editor.

Comment: Alternatively, highlight the text and press CTRL + F2 (or CMD + F2 on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

To change the name at all occurances in current file.

```
1. select the word or var whatever.
2. press shift + F6
3. rename and press Enter
```